# Avoid App crashing when catch Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, crash, try-catch

I have an internet operation that reads line from an online file. It is in a try-catch block. When the execution fails (for example for the missing internet connection) the operation go to catch block and the App crashes. How can I avoid crashes?

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((new URL(MegaMethods.url+params[0])).openStream()), 8192);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    // Here I want to do something to avoid app crash
    }
```

Comment: It will not crash because of the catch clause. It might crash because of the subsequent lines of code which tries to do something based on the server result.

Comment: @Prem It will crash because if I don't have internet there will be a problem with file, it doesn't find file or can't resolve URL, so  it flows to catch. When I have access to catch can I avoid app to crash?

Comment: What do you want the app to do in this scenario?

Comment: @ClearCode can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: @JamesB I want that if I don't have success in my try operations the app doesn't crash, I want to avoid crash

Comment: Your app crashes if it throws an exception which is not caught. Catching the exception automatically prevents the app from crashing from that particular exception. Your problem is not with this block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if the device has network connectivity before trying to fetch the file. If no network is found, then avoid the task.

Code sample - Call this method. If it returns true, network is available.

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    boolean status=false;
    try{
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            status= true;
        }else {
            netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
            if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                status= true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return false;
    }
    return status;

    }
```

Also, I agree with you that, for some reason, application might throw exception and reaches Catch block. But please note that, even if the catch block is empty, it will not crash your application.

Application might crash because of some code outside the try catch block.

Comment: Thank you but my app works with internet! I don't want to check internet because something could go wrong while AsyncTask is running, unfortunatly internet could be go down while loading from internet so I prefer to do something after have got a fail response

Comment: @ClearCode, In that case, you need to do nothing to avoid app crash in catch block. Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: Now I understand, the problem is probably caused by the return value, I do other operations so if "try" doesn't go like I want it cause app crash. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ClearCode, Mark it as answer if it helped you and close the loop.